# Alternative word usage for "I have a degree in"

Tags: synonyms

In my resume, I'd like to say something other than "I have a degree in"  Are there other ways to state this?

Comment: A few alternatives:
- I hold a degree in
- I'm a graduate in
- I have completed

Comment: "I have a double-E"

Answer (score 4):

Many, depending on context:

> My degree is in...
>
> I hold a degree in...
>
> I obtained a degree in...
>
> I studied X in university...
>
> I am a licensed X (this one depends very much on context)

Comment: I successfully studied X... or i completed my studies in X

Answer (score 1):

If it's an undergraduate degree, the most common phrase in American English is "I majored in *_*".

Comment: Assuming one graduated! Anyway....in addition to *all* the above examples, or below examples, depending on how you have the answers ordered on the page, there is "I have earned a degree in..." or "I have an earned degree in..." But on a resume, I would just list the degree and not put it in a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You could say, "I earned a degree in ...."

Answer (score -1):

This is what could be said:

As an alumnus in X university I achieved a degree in X, this proves my overwhelming calibre for the X sector.

### Alumnus= a former pupil or student of a particular school, college, or university.

### Calibre= someone's level of ability